# Increase Android Notification Badge Count?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications

I'm using ShortcutBadger to show a notifcation badge on my app icon: https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

I just want to know how to increase this badge count? Because it always shows me an "1", no matter how many notifcations were sent.

I tried to put `int badgeCount = 1` inside and outside the `sendNotification` method. This is how I implemented it:

```
public int badgeCount = 1;

private void sendNotification(String message, String uri) {    
    badgeCount = badgeCount+1;
    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(getApplicationContext(), badgeCount);
```

It won't increase on new notifications. Any suggestions?

Comment: I saw they had examples in that git. Have you had a look?

Comment: Yes, I used it and it still doesnt increase the badge count @MuliYulzary